# Bootstrap theme js is not working in production but it does in development (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, themes, production

I have a website that is working fine in development mode but it's not working in production. The JavaScript of the theme (admin-lte) seems to break once it is in production environment.

I have executed the `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` command and I have changed `config.assets.compile = false` to `true`.

I have tried adding the `config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']`, too but it's not working.

These are my files right now.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

gem 'sorcery'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-twitter"
gem "omniauth-flickr"
gem 'omniauth-bitly'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth-vimeo'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem "rolify"
gem 'adminlte-rails'
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.9.2"
gem 'ionicons-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'chartjs-ror'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'feedjira'
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'rails-erd'
gem 'railroady'
```

Production.rb

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true #ponía FALSE

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.debug = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I'll appreciate any help or idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In production environment, the rails server does not serve static files like css and js, and rails won't fallback to asset pipeline if compiled css or js is not found. These behaviors is set in your **config/environments/production.rb**:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compile = false
```

You can temporarily set them to `true`, but it will lower down the performance if you really want to make your rails app online.

The recommended way is manually compile the css and js: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, and let Nginx or Apache serve those static files and reverse proxy other requests to your rails server.

Comment: I have already executed that command but it didn't work. The CSS files are found but javascript of the theme still not working.